# How can I UPDATE more rows in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables - Rawdata and Cleandata

Rawdata gets regulary id's and distances

```
INSERT INTO rawdata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('1', '50');
INSERT INTO rawdata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('1', '50');
INSERT INTO rawdata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('2', '100');
INSERT INTO rawdata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('2', '100');
```

Cleandata has only one id.

```
INSERT INTO cleandata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('1', '0');
INSERT INTO cleandata (`ShuttleID`, `Distance`) VALUES ('2', '0');
```

There will be alot of entries in rawdata. My idea is to sum(Distance) and use UPDATE to the Distance in cleandata.

```
UPDATE cleandata cd, rawdata rd SET cd.Distance = cd.Distance + (SELECT sum(Distance) FROM rawdata GROUP BY ShuttleID)
```

My Query is working when i am placing only one ShuttleID. If i place more ID's i get the error

**Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row**

I understand it because the Select statement gives me more rows when i have more id's

My question right now is : How can i alocate the correct Distance from Rawdata to Cleandata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE cleandata cd
    SET cd.Distance = (SELECT SUM(rd.Distance)
                       FROM rawdata rd
                       WHERE rd.ShuttleId = cd.ShuttleID
                      );
```

If you want only rows with matching `ShuttleId`s to be updated, then use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE cleandata cd JOIN
       (SELECT ShuttleId, SUM(rd.Distance) as sum_distance
        FROM rawdata rd
        GROUP BY rd.ShuttleId
       ) rd
       ON rd.ShuttleId = cd.ShuttleID
    SET cd.Distance = rd.sum_distance;
```

And if you want to include the current distance (as opposed to just the calculation), then:

```
UPDATE cleandata cd JOIN
       (SELECT ShuttleId, SUM(rd.Distance) as sum_distance
        FROM rawdata rd
        GROUP BY rd.ShuttleId
       ) rd
       ON rd.ShuttleId = cd.ShuttleID 
    SET cd.Distance = cd.Distance + rd.sum_distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `update` with `exists` as follows:

```
UPDATE cleandata c
    SET c.Distance = (select SUM(r.Distance)
                       FROM rawdata r
                       WHERE r.shuttleid = c.shuttleid
                      )
 Where exists (select 1 from rawdata rr
                Where rr.shuttleid = c.shuttleid);
```